# expected change in value of a derivative in a multicurve framework

Tags: discounting, multicurve

I'm reading Piterbarg [paper](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXltOSnNLMAhXrCpoKHUGbAoUQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.risk.net%2Fdigital_assets%2F895%2F042-048_AR0310_Cuttingedge.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG6XI6nZuW-t9V51jzqZvx79gCRrQ&bvm=bv.121658157,d.bGs), "Funding beyond discounting: collateral agreements and derivatives pricing." and have a question about equation $(6)$.
There he says that for a derivative we have

$$E_t[dV_t]=(r_F(t)V(t)-(r_F(t)-r_C(t))C(t))dt = (r_F(t)V(t)-s_F(t)C(t))dt$$

where $C(t)$ amount in collateral, $r_F$ short rate for unsecured funding, $r_C$ the short rate for risk free rate which corresponds to the safest available collateral, cash and $s_F(t)$ is the funding spread $r_F-r_C$. Why is the above first formula for the expected change in the derivative true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $(2)$ of [Piterbarg](http://www.risk.net/digital_assets/895/042-048_AR0310_Cuttingedge.pdf),
\begin{align*}
V(t) = \Delta (t) S(t) + \gamma(t),
\end{align*}
where $\Delta (t)= \frac{\partial V(t)}{\partial S}$, and $\gamma(t)$ is the cash account that satisfies
\begin{align*}
d\gamma(t) &= \big[r_C(t) C(t) + r_F(t)(V(t)-C(t))-(r_R(t)-r_D(t))\Delta(t)S(t) \big]dt\\
&=\big[r_F(t)V(t) + (r_C(t)-r_F(t)) C(t)-(r_R(t)-r_D(t))\Delta(t)S(t) \big]dt.
\end{align*}
Moreover, based on Equation $(4)$ in the paper,
\begin{align*}
dS(t)/S(t) = (r_R(t)-r_D(t))dt + \sigma_S(t) dW_S(t).
\end{align*}
Then, from the self-financing condition,
\begin{align*}
dV(t) &= \Delta (t) dS(t) + d\gamma(t)\\
&=\big[r_F(t)V(t) + (r_C(t)-r_F(t)) C(t)\big]dt + \Delta (t)S(t)\sigma_S(t) dW_S(t). \tag{E1}
\end{align*}
It is obvious now that
\begin{align*}
E_t(dV(t)) = \big[r_F(t)V(t) + (r_C(t)-r_F(t)) C(t)\big]dt.
\end{align*}

Note that Formulas $(3)$ and $(5)$ in [Piterbarg](http://www.risk.net/digital_assets/895/042-048_AR0310_Cuttingedge.pdf) can also be derived directly from Equation $({\rm E}1)$ above.

Answer (score 2):

self financed portfolio will give you :

$$ dV_t = r_F(t) \underbrace{(V(t)-C(t) - \Delta S_t )}_{\text{cash position}} dt + r_C(t) \underbrace{C(t)}_{\text{posted collateral}} dt + \underbrace{\Delta dS_t}_{\text{market move}} $$

then you retrieve his equation using that under risk-neutral measure :
$$\mathbb{E}[dS_t|\mathcal{F}_t]=r_F(t)S_tdt$$