# Risk-neutral expectation equation with collateral and funding costs

Tags: black-scholes, discounting, collateral

I am looking at a paper by V. Piterbarg, *Funding beyond discounting: collateral agreements and derivatives pricing*, that you can download on the following [link](http://www.risk.net/digital_assets/5582/risk_0210_piterbarg_newer.pdf), in which the author adapts the Black-Scholes pricing framework to introduce collateral and funding at a non-risk-free rate.

Letting $V_t \equiv V(t)$ and $C_t \equiv C(t)$, I am having trouble to go from equation $(3)$...

$$ V_t = E_t \left[ e^{-\int_t^Tr_F(u)du}V_T+\int_t^Te^{-\int_t^ur_F(v)dv}\left( r_F(u)-r_C(u)\right) C_u \ du \right]$$

... to equation $(5)$:

$$ V_t = E_t \left[ e^{-\int_t^Tr_C(u)du}V_T\right]-E_t \left[\int_t^Te^{-\int_t^ur_C(v)dv}\left( r_F(u)-r_C(u)\right) \left(V_u-C_u\right)du \right]$$

According to the author, to go from $(3)$ to $(5)$ we only need to "*rearrange terms*".

Can anybody show how to go from one to the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One derivation is to replace $V_u$ in Equation $(5)$ using the expression given by Equation $(3)$ and then work out to reach $(5)$; see Appendix A in [this paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2220371) for more details. Here, we provide another derivation. See also [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25949/expected-change-in-value-of-a-derivative-in-a-multicurve-framework/25951#25951).

We recall that, from $(2)$ of [Piterbarg](http://www.risk.net/digital_assets/895/042-048_AR0310_Cuttingedge.pdf),
\begin{align*}
V_t = \Delta (t) S(t) + \gamma(t),
\end{align*}
where $\Delta (t)= \frac{\partial V(t)}{\partial S}$, and $\gamma(t)$ is the cash account that satisfies
\begin{align*}
d\gamma(t) &= \big[r_C(t) C(t) + r_F(t)(V(t)-C(t))-(r_R(t)-r_D(t))\Delta(t)S(t) \big]dt\\
&=\big[r_F(t)V(t) + (r_C(t)-r_F(t)) C(t)-(r_R(t)-r_D(t))\Delta(t)S(t) \big]dt.
\end{align*}
Moreover, based on Equation $(4)$ in the paper,
\begin{align*}
dS(t)/S(t) = (r_R(t)-r_D(t))dt + \sigma_S(t) dW_S(t).
\end{align*}
Then, from the self-financing condition,
\begin{align*}
dV_t &= \Delta (t) dS(t) + d\gamma(t)\\
&=\big[r_F(t)V_t + (r_C(t)-r_F(t)) C(t)\big]dt + \Delta (t)S(t)\sigma_S(t) dW_S(t). \tag{*}
\end{align*}

From $(*)$, 
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{-\int_0^t r_F(v)dv}V_t \right) &=-r_F(t)e^{-\int_0^t r_F(v)dv}V_tdt + e^{-\int_0^t r_F(v)dv}dV_t\\
&=e^{-\int_0^t r_F(v)dv}\big[(r_C(t)-r_F(t)) C(t)dt + \Delta (t)S(t)\sigma_S(t) dW_S(t)\big].
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
e^{-\int_0^T r_F(v)dv}V_T-e^{-\int_0^t r_F(v)dv}V_t &=\int_t^Te^{-\int_0^u r_F(v)dv}\big[(r_C(u)-r_F(u)) C(u)du\\
&\qquad + \int_t^T\Delta (u)S(u)\sigma_S(u) dW_S(u).
\end{align*}
Taking conditional expectation with respect to $\mathscr{F}_t$ on both sides, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
E_t\left(e^{-\int_0^T r_F(v)dv}V_T \right)-e^{-\int_0^t r_F(v)dv}V_t &=E_t\left(\int_t^Te^{-\int_0^u r_F(v)dv}\big[(r_C(u)-r_F(u)) C(u)du\right),
\end{align*}
which leads to Equation $(3)$ in [Piterbarg](http://www.risk.net/digital_assets/895/042-048_AR0310_Cuttingedge.pdf), that is,
\begin{align*}
V_t &= E_t\left(e^{-\int_t^T r_F(v)dv}V_T + \int_t^Te^{-\int_t^u r_F(v)dv}\big[(r_F(u)-r_C(u)) C(u)du\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}

$$$$
To derive Equation $(5)$, we note that, from $(*)$ above, by rearranging terms,
\begin{align*}
dV_t &= \big[r_F(t)V_t + (r_C(t)-r_F(t)) C(t)\big]dt + \Delta (t)S(t)\sigma_S(t) dW_S(t)\\
&=\big[r_C(t)V_t + (r_F(t)-r_C(t))(V_t -C(t))\big]dt + \Delta (t)S(t)\sigma_S(t) dW_S(t).\tag{**}
\end{align*}
As above,
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{-\int_0^t r_C(v)dv}V_t \right) &=-r_C(t)e^{-\int_0^t r_C(v)dv}V_tdt + e^{-\int_0^t r_C(v)dv}dV_t\\
&=e^{-\int_0^t r_C(v)dv}\big[(r_F(t)-r_C(t))(V_t -C(t))dt + \Delta (t)S(t)\sigma_S(t) dW_S(t) \big],
\end{align*}
and, consequently,
\begin{align*}
E_t\left(e^{-\int_0^T r_C(v)dv}V_T \right) -e^{-\int_0^t r_C(v)dv}V_t&=E_t\left( \int_t^Te^{-\int_0^u r_C(v)dv}\big[(r_F(u)-r_C(u))(V_u -C(u))du\right),
\end{align*}
which leads to Equation $(5)$ in [Piterbarg](http://www.risk.net/digital_assets/895/042-048_AR0310_Cuttingedge.pdf) immediately, that is,
\begin{align*}
V_t =E_t\left(e^{-\int_t^T r_C(v)dv}V_T \right) - E_t\left(\int_t^Te^{-\int_t^u r_C(v)dv}\big[(r_F(u)-r_C(u))(V_u -C(u))du \right). \tag{5}
\end{align*}